# Bind ComboBox to Change Another ComboBox with XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, combobox

I've made a small example project to visualize. I have a project with many comboboxes which affect each other that I need to apply this to.

I have two ComboBoxes, **Numbers** and **Colors**.

The ***SelectedItem*** in **Numbers** changes the ***Items*** & ***SelectedItem*** in **Colors**.

**How do I do this with WPF XAML Binding ItemSource and SelectedItem?**

1. Use an ICollection?
2. Add/Remove Items from ObservableCollection?
3. Create a List as the ItemSource for the Collection?
4. Change Items individually with Add()/Remove() or Swap the Entire
   ItemSource for another one?

**comboBoxNumers** = 1, 2, 3, 4

**comboBoxColors** = Red, Green, Blue

- 1 → Red
- 2 → Green
- 3 → Blue
- 4 → Remove Red, Green. Add Yellow.
- 1, 2, or 3 → Remove Yellow (if exists). Add Red, Green (if does not exist).

**1 → Red**

[image: 1 - Red]

**2 → Green**

[image: 2 - Green]

**4 → Yellow (Remove Red/Green)**

[image]

**Old C# Way I've Been Using:**

**Populate ComboBox**

```
List<string> NumbersItems = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
NumbersItems.ForEach(i => comboBoxNumbers.Items.Add(i));

List<string> ColorsItems = new List<string>() { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
ColorsItems.ForEach(i => comboBoxColors.Items.Add(i));
```

**1 → Red**

```
// Numbers 1
if ((string)comboBoxNumbers.SelectedItem == "1")
{
    // Remove Yellow if Exists
    if (comboBoxColors.Items.Contains("Yellow")) { 
        comboBoxColors.Items.RemoveAt(comboBoxColors.Items.IndexOf("Yellow")); 
    }

    // Add Red if Does Not Exist
    if (!comboBoxColors.Items.Contains("Red")) { 
        comboBoxColors.Items.Insert(0, "Red"); 
    }

    // Select Red
    comboBoxColors.SelectedItem = "Red";
}
```

**2 → Green**

```
// Numbers 2
if ((string)comboBoxNumbers.SelectedItem == "2")
{
    // Remove Yellow if Exists
    if (comboBoxColors.Items.Contains("Yellow")) { 
        comboBoxColors.Items.RemoveAt(comboBoxColors.Items.IndexOf("Yellow")); 
    }

    // Add Green if Does Not Exist
    if (!comboBoxColors.Items.Contains("Green")) { 
        comboBoxColors.Items.Insert(1, "Green"); 
    }

    // Select Green
    comboBoxColors.SelectedItem = "Green";
}
```

**4 → Yellow (Remove Red/Green)**

```
// Numbers 4
if ((string)comboBoxNumbers.SelectedItem == "4")
{
    // Remove Red if Exists
    if (comboBoxColors.Items.Contains("Red")) { 
        comboBoxColors.Items.RemoveAt(comboBoxColors.Items.IndexOf("Red")); 
    }
    // Remove Green if Exists
    if (comboBoxColors.Items.Contains("Green")) {
        comboBoxColors.Items.RemoveAt(comboBoxColors.Items.IndexOf("Green")); 
    }

    // Add Yellow if Does Not Exist
    if (!comboBoxColors.Items.Contains("Yellow")) {
        comboBoxColors.Items.Insert(0, "Yellow"); 
    }

    // Select Yellow
    comboBoxColors.SelectedItem = "Yellow";
}
```

Comment: Write a viewmodel. "Add/Remove Items from ObservableCollection". Bind collections to `ComboBox.ItemsSource`, don't ever touch `Items` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by having two ICollections in a ViewModel that will be set as datacontext of your window. This is much better approach and focuses on data binding and MVVM.
Also, bind SelectedItem of one comboBox to a property in the viewmodel. So, when a number will be selected from first combo, it will call the setter of the bound property and inside this setter, you can modify the second ICollection (Colors) which will be bound to second combobox  i.e.

```
<ComboBox name="numberCmb" ItemsSource = {Binding Numbers} SelectedItem ={Binding SelectedNumber../>

<ComboBox name="colorsCmb" ItemsSource = {Binding Colors} SelectedItem ={Binding SelectedColor../>
```

And in ViewModel

```
public ICollection Numbers {get;set {RaisePropertyChanged("Numbers")}
public ICollection Colors {get;set {RaisePropertyChanged("Colors")}

public int SelectedNumber 
{
get{ return _selectedNumber; }
set
{
_selectedNumber = value;
RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedNumber");
//
Here Modify the Colors collections by calling other method which can filter or modify Colors using LINQ i.e.
ModifyColorsCollection(value);
    //
}
```

You can create the method like

```
public void ModifyColorsCollection(int number)
{
//Logic to modify Colors collection here only
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and get back on how it goes.